# Android soft Keyboard not open on Edit Text Click Event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I m developin Tab based Application in which first activity contain one edit text and one button ..on button's click event i started thread and parsed the data based on edit text's search criteria.and after parsing successfully i replace the activity grop's content view to next activity...
now the problem is that,when i came back to first activity from second activity ,when i click on edit text it doesnt open he android soft keyboard..

can any one help me whats happening..

i also tried to open android soft keyboard programmetically..bt it is not noot working ..

here is my code to open keyboard programmetically..

```
  InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
                mgr.showSoftInput(etSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would help,

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  if(m != null){
      m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   }
```